# Missing assembly reference in windows universal app

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app

I've been working on windows 8.1 universal app. everything works fine except for build errors when I am trying to build the entire solution. No errors if I am trying to build the project.

The error is:
The type of namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I installed json.net via NUGet, i can run the application without any issue. but when I build the solution, it failed.

The reason why I want to get this work is I want to add unit testing to the project and it requires to build the solution without any error.

I am new to .NET development. Thanks in advance if anyone could offer help.

Comment: Deleting the old reference, if its there, and adding a fresh new reference to that assembly should work it out.

Comment: How can You run Your app if You can't build it ?

Comment: Go to location of your bin folder and try to find Newtonsoft dll is available or not.If yes try to add the reference again.Else download the dll from internet and add it.

Comment: @MajkeloDev I can build the project and run, but cannot build the whole solution. I only see errors when I am trying to build the solution.